# Queries related to Google cloud storage and Aws bucket for file storage

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

there.I am moving forward to use google cloud services to store Django media files. But one thing that stops me is about the Google and Amazon free tier. I had read the google cloud docs but I am confuse about many things. For free tiers, New customers also get $300 in free credits to run, test, and deploy workloads. What I want to know is if they are  gonna automatically charge me for using the cloud-storage after 3 months of trial is over because I am gonna put my bank account. This case is same on Aws bucket which allows to store mediafiles for 1 year after then what's gonna happen. Are they auto gonna charge me?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used google cloud before. For AWS free tier you can use the storage with the limited features they allow to free tier. Regarding charges, you can definitely setup a cloudwatch alert in AWS which will alert you if your usage is beyond the free tier limit or you are about to get charged. So you can set that up and be assured you won't get surprise before you get alerted for the same.
Hope this helps. Good luck with your free tier experience.

Comment: So then after,I won't be charged? Can I pause things?.Because ,I have read the docs they said they"ll auto charge after free tier limi

Comment: You need to setup cloudwatch alert to get alert when you are going beyond free tier limit. You can find this setting in your AWS account as well.